# Configuring an EC2 instance using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, phpseclib

I currently use Codeigniter for my webapp. I would like to SSH into an EC2 instance and run a set of scripts as ec2-user. The problem with PHPsecLib is that it somehow doesn't run commands in sudo mode. Any tips for this? I have tried the $ssh->exec extensively. but my bash script that resides on the server fails to execute. Is there a better way of running a bash script that resides on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phpseclib docs talk about how to use sudo with phpseclib:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo,

The code:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
}
?>
```